# Kendoui Mvc samples and dll version

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have downloaded the KendoUI sample from
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/tutorial-saleshub/kendo-saleshub-intro

I have: *VisualStudio 2013 AND *KendoUI trial version: 2014.2.903.545

In references section of this sample, Kendo.Mvc was marked yellow therefore i replaced it by adding mine version. Still I am getting following error.

> Warning   1   The primary reference "Kendo.Mvc" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".   SalesHub.Client

How can i get the older version to run this sample? Or these sample are simply obsolete and no more maintained. I am facing same issues nearly with all the samples downloaded. If i upgrade the sample project to higher version of .NET framework then obviously other packages started to cry.

> Warning   10  Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed. SalesHub.Client

--

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change the target framework for the project.

If you right click the project go to properties and select application you will probably see that the project is targeting the 4.0 framework.

Just change this to 4.5 and the project should build and run for you.

Comment: Thanks! but this is what i have already mentioned in my last paragraph

Comment: This artical finally resolved all the references (suggested by telerik team) http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/upgrade-guide/getting-started-root-migration-tool-upgrade-references. I also have to put the Kendo.Mvc.dll (compiled for .NET 4) in the libs folder.